# Including Google Analytic tracking code dynamically at bottom of page after </Form> tag

Tags: c#, javascript, google-analytics

I have a web application in which I want to track two different views of the same page from `google analytic`.

From code behind I am managing the two different views..but didn't find the way to manage the below script from code behind.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    try {
        var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("XX-XXXXXX-XX");
        pageTracker._setDomainName(".DOMAIN.com");
        pageTracker._trackPageview();
    } catch (err) { }
</script>
```

So how can I change this script dynamically from code behind...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hack will be to place two hidden fields in the aspx part

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="TrackerCode" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
</asp:HiddenField>
<asp:HiddenField ID="DomainName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
</asp:HiddenField>
```

Then at page load assign them

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        TrackerCode.Text = "XX-XXXXXX-XX";
        DomainName.Text = ".DOMAIN.com";
    }
}
```

And finally place your script at the bottom of the page. ( After the labels we created )

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    try {
        var tcode = document.getElementById("TrackerCode").value;
        var domain = document.getElementById("DomainName").value;
        var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker( tcode );
        pageTracker._setDomainName( domain );
        pageTracker._trackPageview();
    } catch (err) { }
</script>
```

Comment: By viewing the `HTML` code I can see only this: `var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker(tcode);` instead of `var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker('XX-XXXXX-XX');` even if I am getting the value on `alert`...@naveen

Answer (score 0):

Declare one function and define all your logic inside this function.

And call that function when the DOM is ready or on window.onload.

```
window.onload=function(){
              //your function called it here or right your code here
}
```

Hope it will work